# webapp - SRVE0278E: Error while adding servlet mapping --> /*

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, websphere

I've set the value

```
<jsp-attribute name="fileServingEnabled" value="false"/>
```

according to [IBM Support discussion](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI05054).

But also I'm getting this error:

```
webapp - SRVE0278E: Error while adding servlet mapping --> /*.
```

I've included the most part of my code required in my previous question Running [Spring Boot Application on WebSphere 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754752/running-spring-boot-application-on-websphere-9/41757582#41757582)

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE and websphere 9.0.0.1 traditional.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you set this value? It should be put in the `ibm-web-ext.xml` NOT `.xmi` file. Also make sure that it is included in your built application.

Comment: @Gas yes i have put it into .xml and what do you mean by 'build application '?? If it is war file, then yes it is in war file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this page [Configuring JSP engine parameters](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tweb_jspengine.html). It should be specified via:

```
 <enable-file-serving value="false"/>
```

not `<jsp-attribute>` element.

Here is sample from documentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
   xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd"
      version="1.0">

   <default-error-page uri="error.jsp"/>
   <jsp-attribute name="useThreadTagPool" value="true" />
   <jsp-attribute name="verbose" value="false" />
   <jsp-attribute name="deprecation" value="false" />
   <jsp-attribute name="reloadEnabled" value="true" />
   <jsp-attribute name="reloadInterval" value="5" />
   <jsp-attribute name="keepgenerated"  value="true" />
   <jsp-attribute name="trackDependencies" value="true" />
   <reload-interval value="9"/>
   <auto-encode-requests value="true"/>
   <auto-encode-responses value="false"/>
   <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
   <enable-file-serving value="false"/>
   <pre-compile-jsps value="false"/>
   <enable-reloading value="true"/>
   <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="true"/>
</web-ext>
```